# How can I resolve 400 status code by sending POST in Golang?

Tags: go

I have Python script, that works fine

```
def register():
url = prime_url + '/v2/mobile/user/register?lang=ru'
payload = {
            'email' : 'test@test.test.mail.com',
            'deviceId' : 'testId',
            'password' : 'Test1234'
}
response = requests.post(url, data = payload)
print(response.text)
```

Response:

> {"success":true,"data":"SUCCESS_FIRST_STAGE_REGISTER","params":"Two-factor authentication code sent to test@testtest.test.mail.com","code":200,"runTime":2.391624927520752}

I wrote code on Golang:

```
func postRequest(target string, params string) {
var jsonStr = []byte(`{"email":"testtestetetsees@mail.ru", "deviceId":"ftefst891", "password":"qwertyQwerty132"}`)

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", target, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

var result map[string]interface{}
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result)
fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Response:

> map[code:400 data:ERROR_VALIDATE params:map[deviceId:[Device Id cannot be blank.] email:[Email cannot be blank.] password:[Password cannot be blank.]] runTime:0.023465871810913086 success:false]

I see that problem is by sending JSON string. What should I do?

Comment: Change Content-Type to `application/json`, or change content to urlencoded form.

Comment: It's important to get JSON as string. Because I read it from file

Comment: I try already `application/json`, and still have 400.

Comment: then send the content as urlencoded form and not as json.

Comment: The Python script is using data=payload which sends url encoded data automatically (if you wanted to send json you would use json=payload).  And you set the Content-Type in the golang script correctly to url encoded data, but you don't actually url encode the stuff you are sending.  You need to change `{"email":"testtestetetsees@mail.ru", "deviceId":"ftefst891", "password":"qwertyQwerty132"}` to `email=testtestetetsees@mail.ru&deviceId=ftefst891&password=qwertyQwerty132`  Maybe golang has a function to do that but if not you will need to make your own.

Comment: something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/zv4toMjBCfr

Comment: Use [Client.PostForm](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm).

Comment: Thanks all of you. I don't know how to "increase" your answers

Comment: @mkopriva can you please publish your comment as answer. I wrote self the code https://play.golang.org/p/tLWfmBf5Eka, but you do it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Peter in the comments you can use [`PostForm`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#PostForm) once you convert the data into `url.Values`.

---

If the server expects content in urlencoded form but the input you have is json you'll have to convert it first.

```
var data = []byte(`{"email":"testtestetetsees@mail.ru", "deviceId":"ftefst891", "password":"qwertyQwerty132"}`)

m := map[string]string{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

v := url.Values{}
for key, val := range m {
    v.Add(key, val)
}

resp, err := http.PostForm("https://example.com", v)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// ...
```

If the input you have is already in urlencoded form but it needs escaping you can parse it using `url.ParseQuery` and let the result of that do the escaping.

```
var data = "email=testtestetetsees@mail.ru&deviceId=ftefst891&password=qwertyQwerty132"

v, err := url.ParseQuery(data)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

resp, err := http.PostForm("https://example.com", v)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Mention content type as `"application/json"`

For simplicity you can use http.Post, use the below code as a example:

```golang
resp, err := http.Post(target, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("{\"email\":\"testtestetetsees@mail.ru\", \"deviceId\":\"ftefst891\", \"password\":\"qwertyQwerty132\"}")))
```